# Design page layout using CSS/Div like HTML table

Tags: html, css

Since i am new to CSS, i am not sure if the following page layout is possible using Div/CSS or shall i use HTML table?.

i want to design my page such that, Left side (i.e around 30%) divide into 3 parts with some margin (i.e one Column and 3 rows) and rest of the page in 2 rows (i.e one Column and 2 rows).

Not sure if i could explained it properly. I have the image file but Stackflow does not allow me to upload because of less reputation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to use `<table>` for the layout you described *(and you won't need anything CSS3 or HTML5 specific)*.

There are a few options for implementing this layout.  Here's a good tutorial on CSS layout:

- [CSS Layouts](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/)

Here is one example of your layout:

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kn8QL/)

HTML

```
<div class="left-column">
  <div>Left Side Row 1</div>
  <div>Left Side Row 2</div>
  <div>Left Side Row 3</div>
</div>
<div class="right-column">
  <div>Right Side Row 1</div>
  <div>Right Side Row 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left-column, .right-column{
  float:left;
}
.left-column{
  width:30%; 
}
.right-column{
  width:60%; 
}
div{
  padding:10px;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
```

Screenshot of results

[image: Screenshot of rendered HTML]

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to make table by `div/css`

```
- html

    <div id="container">
      <div id="row">

        <div id="left">
            <h4>Left Col</h4>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>

        <div id="middle">
            <h4>Middle Col</h4>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>

        <div id="right">
            <h4>Right Col</h4>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

- css

> #container {
>       display: table;
>       }
>
> #row  {
>       display: table-row;
>       }
>
> #left, #right, #middle {
>       display: table-cell;
>       }

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you either want a two-column or three-column layout.  Here's a few links for understanding how to create either:

**2-column:**
http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/

**3-column:**
http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/how_to_create_a_3-column_layout_with_css/