# CSS <td> width not covering 100% of table

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to format a table using CSS. The table has three `<td>` which would cover 20%/60%/20% of the table width but the last td goes to the next line instead of staying in the same line.

Here is the CSS for the table:

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#left_menu{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000000;
}
#content{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000000;
}
#right_menu{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000000;
}
```

The website is http://homeworkwizzard.com if you want to see how it looks. Any help as to why this is happening please?

Comment: This isn't the 1990s, please don't abuse tables for layout.

Comment: Please provide a *complete*, reduced test case *in the question*. Questions should not depend on external URLs with content that might change (and definitely shouldn't depend on external URLs where the content will change as soon as you solve the problem).

Comment: Hey the problem was solved by jammykam but what do you guys think should be used for layout instead of tables?

Comment: Stylesheets. They became decent layout tools when CSS 2 came out about 15 years ago (and practical a few years later when browser support improved).

Comment: Thank you, I'll start learning about stylesheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments, you should really NOT be using tables for laying out design. If you are learning, then you should learn properly from the start so you do not get into bad habits.

That said, to answer your question. The issue is with the `float:left` you are using for everything, I assume you are trying to align the text to the left, in which case you should use `text-align: left;`

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vL2U/)

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr id="banner">
        <th colspan="3">Banner</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="body">
        <td id="left_menu">Left Menu</td>
        <td id="content">Content</td>
        <td id="right_menu">Right Menu</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="footer">
        <td colspan="3">Footer</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
html{
    padding: 5% 10%;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    background-color: #FEFFAF;
    background-size: 100%;
}
body { 
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 500px #888888;
    background: #e3e0c0;
    opacity: 0.85;
}
table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#banner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    text-align: left;
}
#body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
#footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
}
#left_menu{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000000;
}
#content{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000000;
}
#right_menu{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it. One questions, what should be used instead of tables for layout design?

Comment: @JavierCarmona You should be using any HTML element including, but not limited to, `div`, `span`, `p`, `a` and styling them using CSS either using direct element selectors, IDs or class  attributes. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917791/design-page-layout-using-css-div-like-html-table

Comment: I can't think of any good tutorials off the top of my head, it's been a long time since I had to look at one, but try [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/rock-solid-css-layouts/) or [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/breaking-out-of-the-box/) but ignore the XHTML stuff, it's not relevant any more. I would put more focus on HTML5 and CSS3.