# how to insert correctly in javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, input, insert

Hello. I have a function to add row. I just added a second input but I don't know how to insert it correctly.

My JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
$(function(){
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
        counter += 1;
        $('#container').append(
                '<strong> No.        ' + counter + '</strong>' 
                + 
                '<strong>       ........................        Client ' + counter + '</strong><br />' 
                +
                '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" />'
                +
                '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfieldstest[]' + '" type="text" /><br />'

                );



    });
});

</script>
```

How I insert:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
    if ($_POST['dynfields']) {

        // HERE WHERE IT'S DOEST WORK //

        foreach (array_combine( $_POST['dynfields,dynfieldstest'] as $key=>$value, $key=>$value1 )) {

            $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            $values1 = mysql_real_escape_string($value1);
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO recherche (hobbies,client) VALUES ('$values', '$values1')", $connection );  

        }
    }

    echo "<i><h2><strong>" . count($_POST['dynfields']) . "</strong> Info Added</h2></i>";
    mysql_close();
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: try `array_combine( $_POST['dynfields'], $_POST['dynfieldstest'])` instead

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\auto\index.php on line 37 here the error with that `code if ($_POST['dynfields']) {
foreach (array_combine( $_POST['dynfields'], $_POST['dynfieldstest']) as $key=>$value, $key=>$value1 )) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're looking for a solution that will scale as more and more inputs are added to the form. Here's a simpler way. It assumes that for each `dynfields` there will be a corresponding `dynfieldstest`, and we can count the number of `dynfields` in order to control the loop.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {

    if ($_POST['dynfields']) {

    $post_count = count($_POST['dynfields']);

        for ($i=0;$i<$post_count;$i++) {

            $values = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dynfields'][$i]);
            $values1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dynfieldstest'][$i]);
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO recherche (hobbies,client) VALUES ('$values', '$values1')", $connection );  

        }
    }

    echo "<i><h2><strong>" . count($_POST['dynfields']) . "</strong> Info Added</h2></i>";
    mysql_close();
}
```

Also, it's time to stop using the deprecated mysql functions. Switch to [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for MySQL only, or if you switch to [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you can interface with MySQL and lots of other database types (MSSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc...).

Comment: error that show me : `code" . count($_POST['dynfields']) . " Info Added

"; mysql_close(); } ?> ` on my page.

Comment: You are breaking out of PHP somewhere with a stray ?> tag. That's why the code is appearing on the page instead of being parsed as code.

Comment: you are right and that work thanks a lot so I checked for the solution if people want to know

Comment: Just a little question when I add row how I divide them correctly cause I ajust with some dot and really noob for my part. ( reference :   '<strong>       ........................        Client '

Comment: You can use tables or divs and CSS to align HTML elements. The best way to do it is divs and CSS, since tables are really for tabular content. Take a look at this question and answer: [Design page layout using CSS/Div like HTML table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917791/design-page-layout-using-css-div-like-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

You should insert all new rows at once. 
And use mysqli or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) in the future, not the old mysql_* functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
$(function(){
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
        counter += 1;
        $('#container').append(
                '<strong> No.        ' + counter + '</strong>' 
                + 
                '<strong>       ........................        Client ' + counter + '</strong><br />' 
                +
                '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" />'
                +
                '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" /><br />'

                );



    });
});

</script>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
    if (is_array($_POST['dynfields'])) {
        foreach($_POST['dynfields'] as $key=>$value) 
        {

            $hobbies = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
            $client = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
            $queryStr[] = "('$hobbies', '$client')";  


        }

        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO recherche (hobbies,client) VALUES ".implode(',',$queryStr), $connection );  
    }
    echo "<i><h2><strong>" . count($_POST['dynfields']) . "</strong> Info Added</h2></i>";
    mysql_close();
}
```

To add new input simply add

```
            +
            '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" /><br />'
```

to the js

Comment: its do not add correctly its add all column in the data hobbies and they add the count in the data client 1..2..3..4

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. You want to add hobbies for each client?